# How do I plot based on all values in two separate columns?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the winrates of Reinhardt at all ranks by three platforms, XBL, PSN, and PC. I want the bar graph to have three x values, one for each platform. I am having an issue graphing using two separate columns as data.

I have tried the following:

```py
df[(['Hero'] == 'Reinhardt') & (['Rank'] == 'All')].plot.bar(x='Platform', y='Win_rate')
```

This gives the error: KeyError: False

```py
df[.loc[df['Hero'] == 'Reinhardt' & df['Rank'] == 'All']].plot.bar(x='Platform', y='Win_rate')
```

Which gives: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

I expect a three bar graph to appear with the x labels being PC, XBOX, and PSN and the y-axis being winrates. Sorry if this has been asked before, but I seem to have hit a dead end.
Here are the columns:
[Dataframe with all Reinhardt values, can't direct paste because of reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgnqw.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: and please post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated some sample data with this code, please state if the format is correct:

```
In[1]: 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

hero = np.random.choice(['Ana', 'Reinhardt', 'Widow', 'Hanzo', 'Torb'], 30)
platform = np.random.choice(['XBL', 'PSN', 'PC'], 30)
winrate = np.random.rand(30) * 100

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hero': hero,
                   'Platform': platform,
                   'Winrate': winrate})

unique = df.groupby(['Platform', 'Hero']).agg({'Winrate': 'mean'}).reset_index()
unique.head()

Out[1]:     
    Platform    Hero        Winrate
0   PC          Ana         33.721728
1   PC          Hanzo       27.350393
2   PC          Reinhardt   60.182229
3   PC          Torb        71.929657
4   PC          Widow       51.911960
```

The most comfortable way to plot the data in groups is to use `seaborn`, which is built ontop of matplotlib (See [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html))

```
In[2]: import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=unique, x='Hero', y='Winrate', hue='Platform')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Is there a way to add a second parameter to hue, I have the winrate for each rank and I'd like to just plot the ones where rank is specified as 'All' rather than dropping the other ranks and making a new data frame. Thank you for the advice though, it helps a lot!.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it thanks to this advice, I created a new data frame with just Reinhardt values using 'Reinhardt = df.loc[df['Hero'] == 'Reinhardt']' then I plotted it using Seaborn: sns.barplot(data=Reinhardt, x='Hero', y='Win_rate', hue='Platform')

Comment: Could you prove your point that reinhard has higher winrate on consoles because you don't have to aim? :D Just kidding. Glad you solved it. Feel free to rate and/or accept the answer.